# Differentiate between calling an unique argument and providing a string along with it using argparse in a mutual exclusive group

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have been checking and I cannot find this functionality.

This is an extract of the help functionality of the script I am writing, as an example:

```
usage: my_parser.py [-h] (-s SERIAL_NUMBER | -e EVENT)
```

And I want my script to accept, for example:

```
$ my_parser.py -s
$ my_parser.py -s 1234
$ my_parser.py -e
$ my_parser.py -e 9876
```

The logic is that if no argument is passed to `-s` or `-e`, then the software must return all entries. If an argument is passed, like `-s 1234` or `-e 9876` then only the entry with that ID must be returned.

The partial code looks like the following:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
group_input = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group_input.add_argument("-s","--serial-number", default=1) # also, default=None
group_input.add_argument("-e","--event", default=1) # also, default=None
```

But then, when I run it, if no argument is provided, the software errors and exits. For example: `$ my_parser.py -s`

I also tried to add something like `action='store_true'` within the `add_argument` function, without success. Why? I assume that it doesn't expect any incoming arguments.

Anyway, even if we could make it work, how to differentiate it?
For example, if I could make the software continue running, let's imagine I introduce the following:

```
$ my_parser.py -s 1234
```

If we parse it, and save it to a variable `a`, then `a.serial_number` is 1234, but `a.event` is 1. I even didn't mention `-e` in the script and it already has a value. So that would be another problem to face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add `nargs='?' to the arguments.  This allows for a 3 way input - a default, a constant, and user value.

The fact that you are using these in a mutually exclusive group doesn't matter.

```
In [3]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: group_input = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
   ...: group_input.add_argument("-s","--serial-number", default=1,nargs='?',const=2,type=int); 
   ...: group_input.add_argument("-e","--event", default=1,nargs='?',const=3,type=int);
   ...: 
   ...: 
In [4]: parser.parse_args('-s'.split())
Out[4]: Namespace(event=1, serial_number=2)

In [5]: parser.parse_args('-s 1234'.split())
Out[5]: Namespace(event=1, serial_number=1234)

In [6]: parser.parse_args('-e'.split())
Out[6]: Namespace(event=3, serial_number=1)

In [7]: parser.parse_args('-e 1232'.split())
Out[7]: Namespace(event=1232, serial_number=1)

In [8]: parser.parse_args('-e 1232 -s'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] (-s [SERIAL_NUMBER] | -e [EVENT])
ipython3: error: argument -s/--serial-number: not allowed with argument -e/--event
....
```

Because the group is `required` you have to provide one of `-s` or `-e`

```
In [9]: parser.parse_args(''.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] (-s [SERIAL_NUMBER] | -e [EVENT])
ipython3: error: one of the arguments -s/--serial-number -e/--event is required
....
```

A `store_true` argument can also be used.